# unable to install jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, macos

im trying to install jupyter-notebook. I run jupyter --h command and it shows the following
`jupyter core     : 4.6.3 jupyter-notebook : not installed qtconsole        : 4.7.6 ipython          : 5.10.0 ipykernel        : 4.10.1 jupyter client   : 5.3.5 jupyter lab      : 0.33.12`

so to install i run pip install jupyter-notebook
it shows this error which im uable to understand

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter-notebook (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV0Wu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what IDE you use, you can switch to VS Studio I use it for Python, C#, Java, Dart, etc and its really good so you can use it on multiple langauges and if you install the Python Extension Jupiter Notebook comes built in

Comment: but why am i not able to install jupyter notebook in my pc

Comment: by your code it seems you're trying to run a jupyter command without it installed. try running pip install jupyterlab and then pip install notebook in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

The error hints at the absence of "QTConsole". Perhaps, you could try to install that using -

```
pip install qtconsole
```

Essentially, the rule of the thumb would be that if while installing a particular application, it shows an error of this type, it means that it has a dependency which needs to be installed before you can proceed. You can check which versions it has had so far and find a compatible version for the application that you are looking to download.

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/qtconsole/

Comment: I've installed  qtconsole it is still showing jupyter-notebook not installed when i run jupyter --version. Also when I run jupyter notebook it shows this error :

Comment: : Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter", line 8, in <module>  sys.exit(main()) File "/Users/ujjwal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/sitepackages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 247, in main command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand) File "/Users/ujjwal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 134, in _jupyter_abspath 'Jupyter command `{}` not found.'.format(jupyter_subcommand)
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.

Comment: Have you tried installing via anaconda? If you do that, jupyter notebook comes packaged with it.  
Download instructions - https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual
Once that is down, go to the terminal and type: ```jupyter notebook```

Note: I would suggest creating a new environment with a more recent python, perhaps 3.7.